How to write txt file at same file path but preventing window to update notepad display
I like to show string in notepad for easier debug purpose.
I have been used the following VBA codes to display string for years. I use office 2021.
Public Sub writeTxt(ByVal sOri As String)
    Const sFFPath As String = "D:\Temp.txt"
    Open sFFPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, sOri
    Close #1
    Dim lOpen As Long
    lOpen = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\System32\notepad.exe " & sFFPath, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub

Previously, no matter how many times I ran the procedures, the notepad windows show different text string with the same file location. For example, I ran writeTxt "AA" and writeTxt "BB". There would be two notepad windows showing "AA" and "BB".
However, maybe Window or Office have some automatic update. Now when I ran writeTxt "AA" and writeTxt "BB". Two notepad windows will both display the later string "BB".
I would like to know how can I prevent earlier notepad window to update.
Thanks for your help and sorry for my poor english. Hope I explain myself well enough.

I would say this is not a VBA question - it's simply the new behavior of Notepad. If I were you, I would not create a new file all the time. I would simply add a new line to the same file (use Append instead of Output, optional with a timestamp.

Thank you for your reply. Two windows are more easier for comparison of two long strings. So append may not be suitable for me. Actually notepad++ also have this new behavior. I think it may caused by windows' new behavior. Thanks for your comment. I also tag notepad.

You can force windows to use "old" Notepad. Full instructions are here Open and Use Old Notepad - Shawn Brink
In short - turn off App Execution Aliases for Notepad in Settings. Then run Notepad.exe - I believe your code should just work but I haven't personally tried this in code. Works fine for me "natively"

Thank you for your reply.  I followed the steps and turned off App execution aliases notepad.exe. And VBA throw error Run-time error '5' at the line  lOpen = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\System32\notepad.exe " & sFFPath, vbNormalFocus). So this method may not work.

I've just plugged your Sub into some code and it worked fine for me.  So it's likely to be your environment. Check out this SO solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894706/shell-cmd-in-access-vba-returns-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument

After I reboot, it worked. Thank you.
